# Unable to time-dependently solve a Laplacian using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, differential-equations

This seems to be a bit of a strange one:

I have my equation, defined as:

```
eqn2 = D[u[t, x, y], t] == 0.1*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {t, x, y}] - OverVector[v][t, x, y].Grad[u[t, x, y], {t, x, y}]
```

It is said that OverVector[v] is equal to {y,-x}, so at first I defined `OverVector[v][x,y]={y,-x}`. But this wasn't able to couple with Grad[u[t,x,y]] due to - I think - it not having the same number of variables. So I defined `OverVector[v][t,x,y]={0,y,-x}`, and this seemed to work

I have used NDSolve to solve this for a square region given by the limits below:

```
NDSolve[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]}, u, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This seems to work fine, as I then go on to plot a contour plot for a specific time.

I have tried doing the same for a disk element, rather than for a square region:

```
 NDSolve[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]}, u, 
 Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

But instead of being able to solve this by keeping the time dependance, Mathematica gives this error message:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong with the code here, switching from the square region to the disk region? Why is Mathematica unable to evaluate this time-dependance?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of `OverVector[v]`?

Comment: It is said that OverVector[v] is equal to {y,-x}, so at first I defined OverVector[v][x,y]={y,-x}. But this wasn't able to couple with Grad[u[t,x,y]] due to - I think - it not having the same number of variables. So I defined OverVector[v][t,x,y]={0,y,-x}, and this seemed to work.

Comment: What version are you using? I was able to run both code snippets without trouble on MMA 12.0.0 Win10-64 ([see screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/P1YSExJ.png)).

Comment: Thanks, I tried again after you suggested so and it now seems to work. Weird that it threw up that error previously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want the independent variables of [`Grad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html)and [`Laplacian`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Laplacian.html) to be the spatial variables only. This seems to work on 12.2:

```
eqn2 = D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.1*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - {y, -x} . 
     Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]];
ContourPlot[ufun[0.5, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image: Solution one]

## Update: Using PDE building blocks available in 12.2

There are some new functions available in 12.2 that serve as building blocks to build PDE equations described in [this video presentation](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=488&v=3204). The purpose of these building blocks is to avoid common mistakes in the PDE equation construction.

If possible, it is best to express your equations and coefficient form so that there is a simple mapping to the new building block functions as shown below:

$$m\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

### Option 1: Build using PDE terms

The OP's system is a time-dependent equation containing a diffusive and convective term. Using the new building blocks, we can construct the equation and obtain the same results as follows:

```
vars = {u[t, x, y], {x, y}};
k = 0.1; v = {y, -x};
eqn2 = D[First@vars, t] + DiffusionPDETerm[vars, k] + 
   ConvectionPDETerm[vars, v] == 0
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
ContourPlot[ufun[0.5, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image: Second solution]

### Option 2: Build with components

Another option is to build the PDE equation using PDE components. PDE components are functions that allow you to build PDE operators in common physics domains. For example, heat transfer contains at least a diffusive term, and optionally it can have convection and source terms or be stationary or transient. Therefore, the [`HeatTransferPDEComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) would seem to be a good fit for this problem. One could set up the problem like so:

```
vars = {u[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 0.1, 
   "HeatConvectionVelocity" -> {y, -x}|>;
eqn2 = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
ContourPlot[ufun[0.5, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image: Third solution]

Comment: Many thanks, this looks to be what I was missing.