# Numerical solution to convection-diffusion equation

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method, differential-equations

I'm trying to numerically solve the following equation

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}=D\nabla^2u-\vec{v}.\nabla(u)$$

for which -1 $\le$ x $\le$ 1, -1 $\le$ y $\le$ 1, 0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1 with initial condition u(0,x,y)=sin(πxy) and u(t,x,y)=sin(πxy) and D=0.1 and $\vec{v}$ is {y,-x}.
I've tried doing the following

```
eqn2 = Inactive[0.1*Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {t, x, y}] - {y, -x}*Gradient[u[t,x,y],{t, x, y}]]
pdesol = DSolve[{eqn2, u[0, x, y] == Sin[\[Pi] x y], u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi x y]}, u[t, x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

But an error occurs. I have also tried to use NDSolve, but I get the same error, which is, "equation or list of equations expected instead of...". How could I fix this?

Comment: This question is similar to the one I answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237643/61809).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments, I described a complete description of setting up a well-formed PDE system for a transient convection-diffusion problem in my answer here [237643](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237643/61809).

The workflow for rectangular domain using the [`HeatTransferPDEComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) is shown in the following:

```
vars = {u[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 0.1, 
   "HeatConvectionVelocity" -> {y, -x}|>;
eqn2 = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0
dctemp = HeatTemperatureCondition[True, vars, 
  pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> Sin[Pi*x*y]|>]
ic = u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y];
Ω = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, ic, dctemp}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
ContourPlot[ufun[0.5, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Workflow]

Answer (score 5):

A similar but lower level approach to what Tim suggested is to use [`DiffisionPDETerm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiffusionPDETerm.html) and [`ConvectionPDETerm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvectionPDETerm.html)

```
vars = {u[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
eqn2 = D[u[t, x, y], t] + DiffusionPDETerm[vars, 0.1] + 
    ConvectionPDETerm[vars, {y, -x}] == 0;
```

Boundary conditions are then:

```
bc = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y], True]
```

The rest is then the same:

```
(*
ic = u[0, x, y] == Sin[Pi*x*y];
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, ic, bc}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
ContourPlot[ufun[0.5, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]*)
```

As a side note, you can `Activate` the PDE as follows:

```
Activate[eqn2]
```

which is a prerequisite to use `DSolve`